# hybrid MPI/OpenMP decreasing performance

Tags: multithreading, fortran, mpi, openmp, gfortran

I am trying to add a OpenMP implementation in a MPI 
parallelized (commercial) Fortran code. MPI works well but
still there are some parts of the code (do loops) 
which can be further optimized and I thought it could
be done with OpenMP. I tried a single loop:

```
 sca = ABS(D(1))
 do k = 2, l
    sca = sca + ABS(D(k))
 end do
```

using OpenMP directives:

```
sca=ABS(D(1))
  omp parallel do reduction(+:sca_aux)   !OM  
        do k = 2, l                 
           sca_aux = sca_aux + ABS(D(k))                                                                                                                            
        end do                      
  omp end parallel do
sca=sca + sca_aux
```

I compiled the program with OpenMPI and with the switch `-fopenmp` also.
The entire program is supposed to compute the energy of a molecule. 
There are two issues of which I cannot explain satisfactorily the 
outputs. First, the values of the energies are modified respect to the
pure MPI implementation (just by changing that loop). Second, 
the performance of the program is decreased as the number of threads
increases. The outputs for `time` command are

```
(MPI only)
real    1m8.950s
user    8m46.176s
sys     0m15.188s

one thread
real    1m34.113s
user    12m1.112s
sys     0m21.374s

two threads
real    1m59.998s
user    15m37.755s
sys     0m26.892s
```

that loop is evaluated by all processors, currently I am using
8 (`mpirun -np 8 ./exec` ). The situation is worst if I increase
the number of threads. Other switches I use to compile the 
program are:

```
 -Impi -DGNU   -I.  -fopenmp -fpreprocessed -c -O2 -ffree-form
```

Is it true that threads could be simultaneously using the nodes
and therefore performance is decreased? For instance, if I use two
threads in one CPU that could cause a decrease in the performance 
because two task are trying be executed at the same time?

Comment: How many MPI processes you had? There is no reason to add threads if you do not decrease the number of processes at the same time.

Comment: hi, I am using 8 processes (mpirun -np 8), each process is supposed to execute the loop I mentioned in the post. Do you mean that if I add threads for each process there could be an overhead because the threads can overlap on the physical cores? I guess 1 thread is executed by one physical core (1 process) but having two threads on the same physical core can cause an overhead?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention.